# Setting width and height for creating a specgram using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, librosa, spectrogram

I am trying to plot a spectrogram using custom width and height but when I run the followding code it throws me the following error, but when i remove the custom width and height it works fine but it creates the spectrogram in a 515x389

Code:

```
 filename = path
x, sr = librosa.load(filename, mono=True)
widthHeight = (432, 288)
plt.figure(figsize=widthHeight)
plt.specgram(x, NFFT=2048, Fs=2, Fc=0, noverlap=128, cmap='inferno', sides='default', mode='default', scale='dB')
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig("spec.png", bbox_inches='tight', transparent=True)
plt.clf()
```

Error

```
_tkinter.TclError: not enough free memory for image buffer
```

Comment: Width and height are the figure size in inches.  You are making a figure that is 10 m x 8 m and overfilling your memory.

Comment: @JodyKlymak what would be the conversion rate then if i would want to convert it to 432 pixels bv 288 ?

Comment: default 72 pixels per inch

Comment: @JodyKlymak thanks for doing the math. That is pretty funny

Comment: inches to pixels is set by dpi (dots per inch).  Default is usually 100.  But you can specify this in `plt.savefig(..., dpi=200)`.  If you want to specify figures with a certain number of pixels, you just need to know the dpi you will save with.  May as well, use the default, so `widthHeight=(4.32, 2.88)` should get you a figure that is 432x288 pixels.  Note, however, the axes is not 432x288 pixels, the whole figure is.

Answer (score 1):

Width and height are the figure size in inches. I was making a figure that was 10 m x 8 m and overfilling your memory

```
filename = path
x, sr = librosa.load(filename, mono=True)
widthHeight = (5.32, 3.49)
plt.figure(figsize=widthHeight)
plt.specgram(x, NFFT=2048, Fs=2, Fc=0, noverlap=128, cmap='inferno', sides='default', mode='default', scale='dB')
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig("spec.png", bbox_inches='tight', transparent=True)
plt.clf()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to save just the spectrogram data as image, see [How can I save a Librosa spectrogram plot as a specific sized image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56719138/how-can-i-save-a-librosa-spectrogram-plot-as-a-specific-sized-image/57204349#57204349)

If you want to have the plot but use librosa to compute spectrograms instead of matplotlib, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52683474/1967571). This allows using mel-spectrograms etc, common and better performing for Machine Learning etc.